# Open 4 or any number of files in rectangles (dired open all in splits)

Tags: dired

When you have a dired buffer open and it's listing 4 files in a directory,
is there a way to 'open all' the files, and be able to see all the files as 4 split windows in emacs.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. In Dired, **`F`** (command `dired-do-find-marked-files`) displays and visits each of the marked files, or the next prefix-arg number of files.  If you want to mark all of the files then you can use `% m .`.  Or if no files are marked then you can just use `t` to mark them all.
2. If you use [Dired+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) then you can also just use prefix arg `C-u C-u` to act on all files (no need to mark them all). So just **`C-u C-u F` will do what you want.
3. If you use Dired+ then you can even do the same thing for all files in the current Dired buffer and in all marked subdirs, ... recursively.  For that, you use key **`M-+ F`** instead of `F`. (All such recursive-behaving commands are on prefix key `M-+`.)

The number of files that can be displayed this way is restricted by the height of the current window and `window-min-height'.  All of the files are visited, but some of them might not be displayed because there's not enough window space.

But you can also have `F` or `M-+ F` open the files in separate *frames* (any number of them), by setting or binding option `pop-up-frames` to non-`nil`.

Comment: you work sundays too? wow

Comment: No, just playing.